# Sending data with GET to flask Python

Tags: python, html, flask, get

**Hi, I am having a problem to send data from python script to a web page via flask. After runnung code on my webpage it displays information: "none". The server is responding but I think there is a problem with sending data using get. I know that at this stage i can generate data in flask but my goal is to send arduino data from python script to flask and display it on website**

script sending data:

```
import requests
import serial
import time

while True:
    payload = {'c1_temp': '20', 'c1_press': '1013', 'c1_humid': '30', 'c1_gleba': '60'}
    r = requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/czujnik1", params=payload)
    print(r)
    time.sleep(5)
```

flask:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import requests
import time

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
    return render_template("style.css")


@app.route('/czujnik1', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def czujnik1():
    data = []
    c1_temp = request.args.get('c1_temp')
    c1_press = request.args.get('c1_press')
    c1_humid = request.args.get('c1_humid')
    c1_gleba = request.args.get('c1_gleba')
    data.append(c1_temp)
    data.append(c1_press)
    data.append(c1_humid)
    data.append(c1_gleba)
    return render_template("czujnik1.html", data = data)
    return render_template("style.css")
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <div class="logo">KREATYWNA MŁODZIEŻ</div>
        <div class="nav-opts">
            <a href="/">BACK</a>
            <a href="/czujnik1">Czujnik 1</a>
            <a href="/czujnik2">Czujnik 2</a>
            <a href="/czujnik3">Czujnik 3</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="czujnik">
        <h1>Czujnik 1</h1>
        <div class="czujnik-wrapper">
            <div class="czujnik-box">
                <h2>Temperatura(℃)</h2>
                <p>{{ data.0 }}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="czujnik-box">
                <h2>Ciśnienie(hPa)</h2>
                <p>{{ data.1 }}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="czujnik-box">
                <h2>Wilgotność(%)</h2>
                <p>{{ data.2 }}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="czujnik-box">
                <h2>Wilgotność gleby(%)</h2>
                <p>{{ data.3 }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please, do not use bold text. It's like shouting.

Comment: sorry to hurt your eyes

Comment: Try outputting `data` list to console to be sure its not empty before sending it to html templates. And, why do you have two return statements in your route?

Comment: it shows like this in the terminal: ['20', '1013', '30', '60'] and I have removed one of these return statements.

Answer (score 0):

When I do a command `print(r.text)`in the sending script i get something like this

html:

````
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <div class="logo">KREATYWNA MŁODZIEŻ</div>
        <div class="nav-opts">
            <a href="/">BACK</a>
            <a href="/czujnik1">Czujnik 1</a>
            <a href="/czujnik2">Czujnik 2</a>
            <a href="/czujnik3">Czujnik 3</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="czujnik">
        <h1>Czujnik 1</h1>
        <div class="czujnik-wrapper">
            <div class="czujnik-box">
                <h2>Temperatura(℃)</h2>
                <p>20</p>
            </div>
            <div class="czujnik-box">
                <h2>Ciśnienie(hPa)</h2>
                <p>1013</p>
            </div>
            <div class="czujnik-box">
                <h2>Wilgotność(%)</h2>
                <p>30</p>
            </div>
            <div class="czujnik-box">
                <h2>Wilgotność gleby(%)</h2>
                <p>60</p>
            </div>
            <div class="czujnik-box">
                <h2>Do wypełnienia</h2>
                <input type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="czujnik-box">
                <h2>Do wypełnienia</h2>
                <input type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>```
It should be working but it isn't showing like that on the page.
````